# View image on css + php + wordpress card - Need correction

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to use this css card in wordpress

https://codepen.io/ChynoDeluxe/pen/bdXeqQ/

However, I can't see the image of the post.

This is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYoav.jpg

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url(<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('alm-thumbnail'); }?>)">
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you need help with?

Comment: The image does not appear when I use this css code and I replace the image with the php code in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

`the_post_thumbnail` returns the whole image tag, which you're putting inside the css `url()` function. It's causing malformed html and thus what is showing in your imgur picture. What you want is just the url. To get that use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url`. So in your example `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(NULL, 'full')`. The `NULL` value for the first param will tell the function to use the current `$post->ID` value (or you can always define a specific $post, if you don't want the current $post by default).

Comment: Sure no problem. Could you please update your most recent set of source code (with that change) as well as a copy & paste of the output source html from the browser. I don't really need a picture of the browser anymore, just the source code and output code. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I assumed your image size was called `'alm-thumbnail'` based on your original question, but make sure that is correct is well. You may want to change that to `'full'` for the purposes of testing to remove that as a possible issue.